# How to add filtering by id to my user resolver?

Tags: python, flask, graphql, graphene-sqlalchemy, flask-graphql

I have schema.py that goes like this:

```py
import graphene
from app import db
from graphene import relay
from app.models import User as UserModel, Event as EventModel
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyConnectionField, SQLAlchemyObjectType


class User(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class UserConnection(relay.Connection):
    class Meta:
        node = User


class Event(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = EventModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class EventConnections(relay.Connection):
    class Meta:
        node = Event


class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        username = graphene.String(required=True)
        fname = graphene.String(required=True)
        surname = graphene.String(required=True)
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)

    user = graphene.Field(lambda: User)

    def mutate(self, info, username, fname, surname, email, password):
        user = UserModel.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        if user is None:
            user = UserModel(username=username, fname=fname, surname=surname, email=email, password=password)
        else:
            return None
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return CreateUser(user=user)


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()

    # queries that return individual models
    user = graphene.Field(lambda: User, username=graphene.String())

    event = graphene.Field(lambda: Event, title=graphene.String())

    # queries that return all models of given type
    all_users = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(UserConnection)

    all_events = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(EventConnections)

    # resolvers
    def resolve_user(self, info, **kwargs):
        query = User.get_query(info)
        # id = kwargs.get("id")
        username = kwargs.get('username')
        return query.filter(UserModel.username == username).first()

    def resolve_event(self, info, **kwargs):
        query = Event.get_query(info)
        # id = kwargs.get("id")
        title = kwargs.get('title')
        return query.filter(EventModel.title == title).first()


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation, types=[User, Event])
```

and my models go like this:

```py
from app import db
from datetime import datetime


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False)
    is_verified = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    profile_pic = db.Column(db.Text(), default="default.jpg")
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    events = db.relationship("Event", backref="organizer", lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        print(f"User({self.id}, {self.name}, {self.surname}, {self.email}")


class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, default=datetime.now().isoformat())
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
```

So if i want to get all users, i type this:

```
query{
  allUsers{
    edges{
      node{
        id
        username
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I get id, I get something like `"id": "VXNlcjoy"` but in my models id is an int. If i do change my resolver to filter by previously mentioned id, sqlalchemy throws me an error because id in a database is in integer. Then I change my resolver to accept ids as integers, and to filter by true ids. Filtering with resolver works after that change but this happens:

```
{
  user(id: 1){
    id

  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "id": "VXNlcjoy"
    }
  }
}
```

I have thought a bit and I think there is a 2 way about this: 
- make graphql return me back that integer id  that sits in the database 
- somehow make resolver query users and events by string id that graphql gives ("VXNlcjoy")

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, i was overriding graphql reserved variable called `id` that is used for caching and pagination.
In models.py, i renamed column `id` to `uuid` and in table Event

```py
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
```

to

```py
user_uuid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.uuid"), nullable=False)
```

and got this:

```
mutation{
  createUser(email:"saki1@saki.com", fname:"saki",surname:"sakal",username:"saki709", password:"sakisaki"){
    user{
      uuid
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createUser": {
      "user": {
        "uuid": "1",
        "id": "VXNlcjox"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

TL;DR - renamed id to uuid because graphql has it's own variable id